Covariances not below $\Sigma$
$\Sigma_0,\Sigma_1,\dots,\Sigma_K$ are real covariance matrices.
I’m interested in the set of matrices
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^K \left\{x: 0 \preceq x \preceq \Sigma_0, \ x\not\prec\Sigma_k\right\}.$$
I’m looking for a concrete description of this set or of its convex hull.
I haven’t been able to work one out from this definition.
Can anyone provide clues?
Superficially restated, a generic member $x$ has the following properties:

$x$ is positive-semifefinite
$\Sigma_0-x$ is positive-semidefinite
$\Sigma_k-x$ is not positive-definite for $k=1,\dots,K$.


Here's a start, working in dimension $D$.
Write $(v_{k,d}, \sigma_{k,d}^2) \in \mathbb{R}^D \times \mathbb{R}$ as $\Sigma_k$'s $d$-th singular vector and value.
Call each set in that intersection $S_k$ and $S=\cap_{k=1}^K S_k.$
Now $S_k$ is precisely those covariances $x \preceq \Sigma_0$ where $
    v_{k,d}' x v_{k,d} \geq \sigma_{k,d}^2 \text{ for some } d \in [D]$.
That is, $S_k= \cup_{d=1}^D \{x: 0\preceq x \preceq \Sigma_0, \ v_{k,d}'x v_{k,d} \geq \sigma_{k,d}^2 \}$, thus
\begin{equation}
  S = \bigcup_{(d_1, \dots, d_K)} \left\{ x: 0 \preceq x \preceq \Sigma_0, \ v'_{k,d_k}xv_{k,d_k} \geq \sigma^2_{k,d_k},k=1,\dots,K \right\}
\end{equation}
where the union is taken over all $(d_1,\dots,d_K) \in [D]^K.$
Further questions remain:

Is this correct?
The number of union members explodes with $K$ and I think many of those members are redundant.
Is there a more convenient representation or approximation to this set?
For example, starting from $(\Sigma_k)_{k=0}^K$ is there a fast algorithm to find some covariances $(C_n)_n$ whose convex hull contains $S$?

