Intersect polytopes defined by half-planes
Is there a quick way to find this region or its convex hull? $N$ is large, $M=d=5$ or so
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^N \bigcup_{m=1}^M \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d :a_{nm}'x \geq 1\} 
$$

The slow way to do it (the only way I know how) is to rewrite it as a union of some $M^N$ different shapes, taking a union over $(m_1,\dots,m_N)\in \{1,\dots,M\}^N$ and then try and find the convex hull.
This is a huge computation as far as I know.
$$
\bigcup_{(m_1,\dots, m_N)} \left\lbrace  x\in \mathbb{R}^d: a'_{1,m_1} x \geq 1, \dots, a'_{N,m_N} x \geq 1
\right\rbrace
$$

I can think of an approximate way by finding supporting half-planes, by repeatedly scanning hyperplanes through space: For each hyperplane, find the minimum offset that gives the hyperplane a point in the set. That's a supporting half-plane. Repeating for enough hyperplanes yields an outer bound.
What is this method called? I would rather not have to re-implement it

Is the order of intersection / union in the first formula correct?

Yes. This comes out of another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939660/ . Briefly, if you have $\Sigma \succeq 0$ then fixing some unitary matrix $U$, the union describes all diagonal $D$ where $UDU' \not\prec \Sigma$.
